# Best practice to prevent software copy

Tags: publishing, copy-protection

I'm developping an application and I'm looking for some cool informations about protecting it against copy ! Do you guys know some book/articles/any informations about it ?

Thanks in advance for your advices !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy-protection

Comment: which language, what platform are you developing for?

Comment: I'm developping a C++ application with Qt 4.5.2. It's pretty much my first "fully developped" application and I would like It to be perfect :) Beside perfectness (that I will never get anyway), I want to learn a maximum of different things and get experience from the beginning to the "end" of the development of an application... That's why I end up thinking about protecting it against piracy...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have incentives to not copying it.

For instance, Xbox 360 games, that are easily copied, and executed on modded boxes, now tend to bundle codes in the box that unlocks downloadable content in-game. These codes are of course only available to people actually buying the game.

So your best option is to make it a better deal for the guy that buys your software, than it is for the people copying it.

Having said that, that option might not be possible or easily done, in which case you should avoid giving your paying customers too hard a time. For instance, if you add serial numbers with online activation and limited number of activations before they need to call you or sit waiting for you to answer an email, I can guarantee that this way will hurt more than just ignoring the people that copy your software in the first place.

The worst option you can go for is the one that will make some of your paying customers wish they hadn't.

Answer (score 14):

If your software is good, someone will find a way to copy it no matter what you do.

If your software is no good, nobody will bother to copy it.

Most of my software falls in the second category, so I've never bothered with copy protection. Many believe that this is an endeavor not worth the effort.

Comment: Donno if your software is good or not, but your sense of humor has made my day ;-)

Comment: A simple protection for intermediate software is enough. Nobody will put so much effort for intermediate software.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Carl's comment I want to add that a rigid copy protection system can make users really annoyed and so a good software becomes a bad software.

Other than that it really depends on the software what to do - can you expect internet connectivity or might the application be running in a data center behind many firewalls? If the net is available an auto-update service is a nice way to track usage - while you should take privacy into consideration then. Otherwise some random serial number process is often good enough: Those who take the effort to bypass it most likely won't buy the software anyways and for others copy and pasting a serial number might be acceptable. But then again: It depends on the software and the users and ...

Punishing the paying users and making it harder to use the software legally than illegally certainly won't work out.